# Need to save as .png, but I get .jpg

Tags: iphone, png, photo, jpeg, cgcontext

I am saving to the photo Album, I want the file to be a .png but it saves as a .jpeg? Is it even possible to save a .png to the Photo Album?

here is my code:

```
CGContextRef MyCreateBitmapContext (int pixelsWide,int pixelsHigh)
{
    CGContextRef context = NULL;
    //CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    void * bitmapData;
    int bitmapByteCount;
    int bitmapBytesPerRow;
    bitmapBytesPerRow = (pixelsWide * 4);
    bitmapByteCount = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);
    //colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );

    if (bitmapData == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
        return NULL;
    }
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                     pixelsWide,
                                     pixelsHigh,
                                     8,//bits per component
                                     bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                     colorSpace,
                                     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    if (context== NULL)
    {
        free (bitmapData);
        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
        return NULL;
    }
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
    return context;
}
```

and:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender{

    myBitmapContext = MyCreateBitmapContext (400, 300);

    // ********** Your drawing code here **********

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myBitmapContext, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextFillRect (myBitmapContext, CGRectMake (0, 0, 400, 300 ));


    // ********** Your drawing code here **********


    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(myBitmapContext);
    UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];

    //NSData* imdata = UIImagePNGRepresentation ( image );// get PNG representation

    //UIImage* im2 = [UIImage imageWithData:imdata]; // wrap UIImage around PNG representation

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil); // save to photo album

    [image release];

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(myBitmapContext);
}
```

many thanks for any ideas

Comment: `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` takes the image data and writes a jpg to the photo album.  I believe it doesn't care what the underlying image file is.  As a stab in the dark, try `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum`.

Comment: Thanks amattn, I will look into that later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIImage` doesn't have an associated filetype. Your code that takes the `UIImage`, extracts PNG data, and constructs a new `UIImage` is just wasted CPU cycles. The resulting image should be identical to the original. `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()` saves a JPEG because it's assuming that photos being saved to the photo album are, well, photos. And JPEG is the preferred format for photos.

You may want to file a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) requesting a mechanism to save a PNG to the photos album.

Comment: Thanks for that Kevin, I have edited the code to remove the .png element for now. (not tested yet) I can live with .jpegs but I would have prefered .png. Do I even need the line: UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef]; or can I just use imageRef directly in the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum method?

Comment: No, you still need to create a UIImage*. CGImageRef and UIImage are not toll-free bridged. However, UIImage* is really just a wrapper around CGImageRef so you aren't copying the image data when you do that.